# "Aufbringen" in der Bedeutung von "einführen"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Ich bin kein deutscher Muttersprachler und bin kürzlich auf das Wort "aufbringen" gestoßen. Ich wurde überzeugt, dass man es heutzutage immer noch in verschiedenen Bedeutungen gebraucht, die in Duden und DWDS aufgelistet sind, aber bin nicht sicher, ob man etwas wie "er hat eine neue Mode aufgebracht" oder "wer hat denn nur dieses Gerücht aufgebracht?" sagen würde (das habe ich auch in Wörterbüchern gesehen, aber ich habe nicht genug Beispiele aus anderen Sourcen gefunden). Ich wende mich daher an euch: Klingen diese Sätze euch natürlich?

Answer (score 1):

> Wer hat denn nur dieses Gerücht aufgebracht?

Das wird so gesagt.